# Why aren't my two cin statements running towards the end of the program?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am a first year cs major. Today in our lab we had to debug some code and make it work. Below is the result.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   int x = 3, y;
   char myanswer;
   int val= 1;
   int num;

   y = x;
   cout << "y is set to: " << y << endl;


   bool again = true;
   int ans;
   while (again) {
      cout << "Please input a number: ";
      cin >> y;
      if (x > y)
         cout << "X is greater than Y\n";

      else {
         cout << "X is less than Y" << endl;
         cout << "would you like to input another number?" << endl;
         cin >> ans;
         if (ans != 1)
            break;
      }
      cout << "would you like to input another number ?" << endl;
      cin >> ans;
      if (ans != 1)
         again = false;
   }
   for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
      cout << x << endl;

   cout << "What number would you like to find the factorial for? " << endl;


   cin >> num;
   cout << num;
   for (int x = num; x > 0; x--) {
      val *= x;
   }
   cout << "Are you enjoying cs161? (y or n) " << endl;

   cin >> myanswer;
   if (myanswer == 'y')
      cout << "Yay!" << endl;
   else
      cout << "I hope you will soon!" << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

After the cout regarding factorials, the cin's don't work and the user ceases to be able to enter input. So far my lab ta's and friends haven't been able to find the issue. The code has been compiled and exected on both my school's engineering servers and my local computer. On both the error persists.

Comment: what did  gdb show is happening?

Comment: I cannot replicate the error. Other than every time I am asked if I want to type a new number I am asked about it two times in a row. I would have to agree with pm100. What number are you putting for num for factorial?

Comment: i dont get prompted for the num, thats the issue I am having

Comment: @jackattack825 what compiler are you running? You have logic errors in your code of course that I can point out easily. But running this in my terminal and compiling with g++ I can get all the way to the end of your program.

Comment: using g++, i figured out the error from the guy below this, I was putting in y/n instead of 1/0 for the answer to a previous cin that somehow broke the rest of the program

Comment: @jackattack825 that's because you were inserting a `char` instead of an integer. Which breaks your program.

Answer (score 2):

almost certainly this caused an overflow

```
   for (int x = num; x > 0; x--) {
      val *= x;
   }
```

what did you enter for num?

Comment: I am guessing that the respose to `would you like to input another number?` was `y`/`n` while the expected type is an `int`.

Comment: ^^ this guy nailed it, I was inputting an n which booped the whole program, putting in a number fixed it

Comment: @jackattack825, never assume input/output operations succeeded. Always check whether it was successful before proceeding to use the objects. Add code to deal with erroneous input.

Comment: awesome ty, is there a quick explanation tho why using a char instead caused an issue, cuz wudnt it just get it's ascii value compared to 1

Comment: @jackattack825, not it doesn't work like that. It has to be number.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a statement as:

```
cout << "would you like to input another number?" << endl;
```

The first instinct for the user would be to type `y` or `n` as an answer. You can help the user by providing a hint.

```
cout << "would you like to input another number (1 for yes, 0 for no)?" << endl;
```

If you do that, it would be better to be consistent throughout your program. The next prompt that seeks a y/n response must use the same mechanism.

```
cout << "Are you enjoying cs161? (1 for yes, 0 for no) " << endl;
```

Of course, always validate input operations before proceeding to use the data.

```
if ( !(cin >> ans) )
{
   // Input failed. Add code to deal with the error.
}
```